# Django ManyToManyField Validate Unique Set

Tags: django, validation, many-to-many, unique

***models.py***

```
class MyProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    codes = models.ManayToManyField(Code)
```

Hi, I'm trying to validate the ManyToManyField for the unique set. it shoud validate that similar set should not repeat again on another record, In the django docs , it mentioned clearly that ManyToManyField cannot be `unique=True` or `unique_together`. So how can I handle this validation, I am not able to find the solution for this. I request please guide me for some suggestion for this, it will be helpfull for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reference to Array field:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

**Sample Codes : 

Model**

```
class Code(models.Model):
id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
codevalue=models.CharField(max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.codevalue}"
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class MyProduct(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      codes=models.ManyToManyField(Code)
      codesarray = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, 
      null=True),size=8, blank=True, null=True)
```

**form**

```
class MyProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MyProduct
        fields='__all__'
```

**view**

```
from .forms import CodeForm, MyProductForm
from EntityInformation.models import MyProduct
class MyProductView(View):
  template_name = 'EntityInformation/Detail/MyProduct.html'

def get(self, request, name=None):
    myproductform=MyProductForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': myproductform})
def post(self,request, name=None):
    myproductform=MyProductForm(request.POST)    
    if myproductform.is_valid():       

        cleaneddata= myproductform.cleaned_data

        arr =[]
        for val in cleaneddata['codes']:
            arr.append(val)        
        try:
            myproductdoc=MyProduct.objects.get(codesarray = arr)
        except:
            myproductdoc=None

        if myproductdoc is None:
            newproductdoc = myproductform.save(commit=False)
            newproductdoc.codesarray=arr
            myproductform.save()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': myproductform})
        else:
            print("Unique validation error")
```

Above code should help you

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, and i will try this and let you know. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this seems to be valid one

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this. 
But you can store the manytomany field in a array field if you are using postgresql. 
Then later you can override the clean_codes method to validate whether a same set of array available already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please explain me this with a piece of code. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediary model, I prefer this approach anyways it makes things very clear. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Here is a very basic working code example.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='Order',
        through_fields=('customer', 'product'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product} {self.customer}"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['product', 'customer']]
```